# Route to public directory fuelphp

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

I am building an app in fuelphp, and I'd like to route to a page of fully static content. For example, I have a file I'd like to display in `public/assets/html/pages/mypage.html`, but i'd like to see that static content when I navigate to `localhost/myroute`.

How can I write a route that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'myroute' => function () {
        return file_get_contents(DOCROOT.'assets/html/pages/mypage.html');
    }`

Comment: This is indeed the answer, if you need some dynamic logic to route to content. If not, you'd better use webserver rewritting.